# Sickbeard start service on boot not working: Permissions issue?

Tags: permissions, ssh, services, init.d

I've just installed Sick-Beard on my server. Starting the service via SSH works just fine, as I issue the command

```
sudo service sickbeard start
```

However, I can't get the service to start on boot. There are some things I'm quite sure are incorrect, but I don't know what the correct settings should be.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/sickbeard
```

currently shows

```
SB_USER=root
SB_PROFILE=/opt/sickbeard/pid
```

and as for ownership and permissions,

```
ls -l /opt
```

shows

```
drwxrwxrwx 10 root   root   4096 Sep 28 19:24 sickbeard
```

Now, I'm pretty sure I should not be using root everywhere, and instead I've created a user 'sickbeard', but this does not work either, probably since this user doesn't have the right permissions. (What these should be, I don't know.)

Furthermore, I've followed http://vassie.me/installing-sick-beard-on-ubuntu-server/ with respect to `/etc/init.d/sickbeard`

Now, basically, if I issue the first command above (`sudo service sickbeard start|stop`) it works just fine, but without sudo I get

```
diana@SERVER:~$ service sickbeard start
Starting SickBeard
start-stop-daemon: unable to set gid to 0 (Operation not permitted)
```

I'm out of my depth here, have searched back and forth but can't get the service to start without the sudo command which, in my mind, is preventing it from starting on reboot. But I might be wrong, it might be something else entirely, I just don't know what...

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Try this [Some services won't start a startup?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527402/some-services-wont-start-a-startup/528346#528346) and let's see if it is the same issue.

Comment: Yes and no: I learned some useful things, like runlevels ;) Had to add a symlink in /etc/rcN.d to sickbeard first, and then decide on an appropriate time to run it. Three sources that helped me: http://askubuntu.com/a/528346/332446 http://askubuntu.com/questions/90982/how-to-make-a-script-in-init-d-run-later and http://askubuntu.com/questions/72123/how-to-write-an-init-script-that-will-execute-an-existing-start-script

Comment: So, did you solve you issue or need help? To add symbolic link you should use update-rc.d command. Run update-rc.d and service with sudo, don't forget it :)

Comment: Sorry, my reply was unclear: The "yes and no" pertained to whether it was the same issue. After adding the symlink to /etc/rcN.d and setting the name of the symlink so that it is started last, it worked!! :) How should I close this question? Answer it myself?

Comment: Well, although it's not very specific on how to do that, starting Sickbeard later *is* the answer, so yes, flag it as duplicate.

Comment: I improved my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527402/some-services-wont-start-a-startup), adding how to change position for systemV init script, hope this will help you.